# Android Studio if input is Decimal App crashes

Tags: java, android, crash, android-edittext, decimal

I'm programming a App that can calculate grades.

But i've got a problem:

IF the Input in the Edittext is decimal, the app crashes. if the Number is not decimal, it does not crash and gives me the right result.

Here's the Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final Button berechnenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.berechnenButton);

    final EditText note1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note1);

    final EditText note2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note2);

    final EditText note3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note3);

    final EditText note4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.note4);

    final EditText wunsch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.schnitt);

    final TextView ausgabe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ausgabe);



    note1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    note2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    note3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    note4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    wunsch.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    ausgabe.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);









    berechnenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {





            if (note1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                note1.setError("Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein!");

            } else {


                if (note2.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    note2.setError("Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein!");

                } else {

                    if (wunsch.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                        wunsch.setError("Dieses Feld darf nicht leer sein!");

                    } else {

                        double note11 = Integer.parseInt(note1.getText().toString());
                        double note22 = Integer.parseInt(note2.getText().toString());
                        double wunsch1 = Integer.parseInt(wunsch.getText().toString());


                        if (note11 > 6) {

                            note1.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                        } else {

                            if (note22 > 6) {

                                note2.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                            } else {

                                if (wunsch1 > 6) {

                                    wunsch.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                                } else {



                                    if (note3.getText().toString().isEmpty() && note4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {




                                        double res = (-note11-note22+wunsch1*3);

                                        ausgabe.setText(String.valueOf(res));

                                    }


                                    if (!note3.getText().toString().isEmpty() && note4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                                        double note33 = Integer.parseInt(note3.getText().toString());


                                        if (note33 > 6) {

                                            note3.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                                        } else {



                                            double res = (-note11-note22-note33+wunsch1*4);

                                            ausgabe.setText(String.valueOf(res));


                                        }


                                    }


                                    if (!note3.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !note4.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                                        double note33 = Integer.parseInt(note3.getText().toString());
                                        double note44 = Integer.parseInt(note4.getText().toString());






                                        if (note33 > 6) {

                                            note3.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                                        } else {

                                            if (note44 > 6) {

                                                note4.setError("Die Note darf nicht grösser als 6 sein!");

                                            } else {




                                                double res = (-note11-note22-note33-note44+wunsch1*5);

                                                ausgabe.setText(String.valueOf(res));

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

If someone knows what i have done wrong, please write it down below!
I would be very thankful, bc i'm very new to programming! :)
Thanks in advance!

Regards
Dario C.

Comment: Btw you really need to look into restructuring your if else statements, putting too many if else branches inside of each other is pretty bad practice (but isn't too bad for a beginner), in your case you should look into writing return; after an action (whatever was supposed to happen) is finished, then at least half of your if else branches will vanish. Return just stops the current method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really provide the Crash info (Exception) in questions because it makes it way easier to find.

After glancing over your code I'm pretty sure the reason for the Crash is this:

```
double note33 = Integer.parseInt(note3.getText().toString());
double note44 = Integer.parseInt(note4.getText().toString());
```

Integer.parseInt throws an exception when the String can't be converted to an int, in your case 3 can be converted, but numbers like 3.345 aren't ints so they cause the crash

To solve this simply replace all of those calls with this:

`Double.parseDouble(note3.getText().toString())`

The left side is correct already

M.f.G :D

Comment: Hi Merthan! This was the solution to my problem, thank you very much! Finally my App is complete! MfG :D

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as the solution?

By the way, no reason to use "Double" instead of "double" on the left side

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is this:

You have to replace this:

```
double note33 = Integer.parseInt(note3.getText().toString());
```

With:

```
Double note33 = Double.parseDouble(note3.getText().toString())
```

Thanks to Merthan for the Solution!

Comment: There probably isn't a reason to use "Double" instead of "double" on the left side (Double capitalized has some disadvantages, look at boxing/boxed datatypes)